# Reading all waiting lines in a SocketServer handler

Tags: python, socketserver

This is a simple `socketserver` example that should receive a line over UDP and echo it out:

```py
import socketserver

class LineHandler(socketserver.DatagramRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        line = self.rfile.readline().strip()
        print(line)

server = socketserver.UDPServer(('', 4444), LineHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

However if two lines come in at the same time, only the first line is read:

```
(printf 'lol\n'; printf 'what\n') | nc -u localhost 4444
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation kind of suggests that `readline()` will repeatedly call `recv()` until it gets a newline, which would leave the next line in the socket's buffer and lead to `handle()` being invoked again. But this doesn't appear to be the case.

Instead, you can use:

```py
for line in self.rfile:
    line = line.strip()
    print(line)
```